# Cannot call a function from finally exception module

Tags: python, multithreading, function, download

I want to make a call to a function from the finally error detection module with a variable passed. But it shows error as:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

My code is as follows:

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
import MySQLdb
import sys
import time
import signal
#from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config
#from MySQL import row

sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)

def query_with_fetchone():
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",  # your host, usually localhost
                             user="root",  # your username
                             passwd="faheemmcfc",  # your password
                             db="python")  # name of the data base
        cur=db.cursor()
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM down")
        queue=0
        data= cursor.fetchone()
        lastid=data[0]
        print(data[0])
        def check(lastid):
            print lastid
            global last
            last=lastid
            while True:
                cursor.execute("Select * from down where id>%s"%(last))
                data = cursor.fetchone()
                last=data[0]
                print(data[0])
                print data[1]
                #signal.pause()
        check(lastid)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        print'last',last
        time.sleep(30)
        check(last)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    query_with_fetchone()
```

Here my need is to infinitely run the while loop, so whenever a new entry is made in the database it can be retrieved.
When I call the check from finally, it shows error as:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/faheem/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test2.py 1 1
2 CCLEANER 3 FANCONTROL 4 CCLEANER 5 FANCONTROL 6 CCLEANER last 6 6
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/faheem/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test2.py", line 55, in
<module>
    query_with_fetchone()   File "/home/faheem/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test2.py", line 45, in
query_with_fetchone
    check(last)   File "/home/faheem/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test2.py", line 34, in check
    last=data[0] TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please show me how to correct it or provide another method to run the while loop infinitely without allowing it to go to the finally part.
Please feel free to correct the question, as I am not so familiar with stackoverflow.

Comment: Hint:  you're getting an error because 'data' is None.  What are the cases where cursor.fetchone() returns None?

Comment: Well, your query probably returned none.. which is why you can't do data[0]

Comment: `fetchone()` returns  None if no more rows are available.  You should test `if data is None:` etc.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html

Comment: Even more rows are added at real time it shows same error.. I want that we loop to run infinitely checking for a new entry in database... Please give me a solution @cdarke